# Split a repository in two differents

Tags: git

Scenario is represented with the graph below:

```
0 -- A -- B -- C -- D
       \
        E -- F -- G
```

At some point, EFG become another project, and I want to completely cut the tie from 0ABCD and EFG:

```
0 -- A -- B -- C -- D

       E' - F' - G'
```

Comment: Isn't another repository with 0AEFG but without BCD also acceptable? While it's possible to remove history from before E you would loose any links to SHA1 values in commit messages etc. because all commits would be rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the procedure is similar to that described on the github site for removing sensitive data from a repository. This works on a file by file basis, and, dependending on the size of your repository, may take some time. The procedure is described in detail [here](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/), and uses [`git-filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) to rewrite all history to remove all occurences of that file (here named `removed_file`):

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch removed_file' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

This rewrites history, essentially creating new commits with all the history reflected in them, so links to the old commits will not work in the new branch.

I'm assuming you do not want to have the new repositories contain a history where the other part is still present. If this isn't the case, it is as simple as pushing these branches to separate repositories and renaming them as `master` branches.

Answer (score 0):

From my notes:

Say you want to split a git repository into two or more discrete repositories.  You'll want to clone the base repository, then use `git filter-branch` to remove the subdirectories you want to get rid of and simultaneously remove the empty commits.

```
1. Clone the repository
  $ git clone git://git.foo.com/myrepo.git NewProject
  $ cd NewProject

2. Filter the new project to retain only subdirectory "lib"
  $ git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter lib master
```